# Vue js 3 Build index file can't be used for a backend project

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm building a simple dataTable with vue. but the backend only needs a simple html file for it and when I build it, I have my index which works fine with my chrome web server but seems like the backend can't open it and see it the right way. is there any solution? or should I just use vue in a blank html file instead?
I can't use nuxt for this project which it's on force and I'm not familiar with nuxt

Comment: It could depend on your backend, are you sure its in a public folder? what are you using for your server?

Comment: the build folder is dist. I've told them to use all css and ... in their folders and also open it with web server. they're using vscode live server. also the backend is python

Comment: The backend can serve the vue app (by providing `index.html`) with no difference than serving regular html files, ofc the `dist` folder structure should remain the same, but if there is any problem loading the html file, its on the backend not the vue build.